# Constructing a matrix based on different lists with Python

Tags: python

I am going to make the following matrix:

```
 s= [[s11 s12 s13]
     [s21 s22 s23]
     [s31 s32 s33]]
```

where I can obtain each array of the matrix s by:

```
 sii = a(i)  ;  for s11, s22, and s33

 sij = a(i)**2 + 10    ;  for s12=s21, s23=s32, and s13=s31
```

here, ai is a list of data:

```
 a = [0.1, 0.25, 0.12]
```

So when I use the following:

```
import numpy as np 

s = np.ones([3,3])

def matrix(s):
a = [0.1, 0.25, 0.12]
s[np.diag_indices_from(s)] = ai
s[~np.eye(s.shape[0],dtype=bool)] = ai**2 + 10
```

It gives me an error. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint for you on how to manipulate the diagonal and non-diagonal values.

```
import numpy as np

s = np.ones([3,3])

def matrix(s):
    a = [1,2,3]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        s[i,i] = a[i] #  sii = a(i) 
        rc = (i + 1) % len(a)
        val = a[i] ** 2 + 10 
        s[i, rc] = val # sij = a(i)**2 + 10 
        s[rc, i] = val # sij = a(i)**2 + 10 
    return s

print(matrix(s))
```

input:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

output:

```
[[  1.  11.   19.]
 [ 11.   2.  14.]
 [  19.  14.   3.]]
```

Comment: Based on your answer, when I put ai = [0.1, 0.25, 0.12] instead of ai = 1, I don't get anything. Could you give me a hint how to input the list?

Comment: @Fara Can you please give an example of input and output matrices of how your output should look like? You can update your question with that.

Comment: @Fara do you want each element of the out matrix to be a Numpy array?

Comment: I am getting sii and sij (the arrays of the matrix s) as: sii= [0.1, 0.25, 0.12], which locate at the diagonal of matrix s, in total 3 of them, and sij = [0.5, 0.1, 0.2] that these locate at s21, s31, and s32. Here, s21=s12, s23=s32,.... Thanks for the help.

Comment: still not clear what you really want. Please update your question with a clear desired or expected output.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I have just updated the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: One more update. Please check the question. I was not clear about the notations.

Comment: So s11=a(1), s22 = a(2) and so on.

Comment: @Fara here is the updated solution. it should work fine now. I used a simple a = [1,2,3] for demonstration. You can change it according to your own needs.

Comment: Great. Thank you utengr.

Comment: @fara i updated the code a bit. Look at the output if you want something like that?

Comment: Yes. That looks very good. Actually, this is a part of code that I am trying to fit in. Sii is the same formula that I have in the question, but, as for sij, the data is coming from a different list of data saying sij = b(j). I am thinking of two loops with one 'return s'. When I do this, I am getting an incomplete matrix.

Comment: I'd like to raise another question, but looks that I'm not allowed to do it in a week.

Comment: I am raising a new question in a few minutes with matrix topic.